# Stopping the execution of multiprocessing.pool()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am making a call to multiprocessing.pool() as such:

```
to_stop = None

....

def function():

....

   with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=threads) as pool:

        global to_stop
        to_stop = multiprocessing.Event()
        query_results = pool.map(run_worker, query_commands)

....

def run_worker(command):

    global to_stop

    if to_stop.is_set():
        print("\n\nHello\n\n")
        return

...

    if (a certain_condition is met):
        to_stop.set()
        return

    return stuff
```

However, to_stop.is_set() is always returning false, despite the fact I am setting it once a condition is met (which I have checked). The reason why I want to check to_stop.is_set() is because I want to cancel the execution of the run_worker function once a certain condition is met. This does not appear to be working and I want to know why, and if there is an easier way of doing this.

I have noticed that "Hello" in the if to_stop.is_set() condition is never printed, meaning that to_stop.is_set() is never True. Why is that the case?

Thank you

Comment: Does `Hello` ever get printed?  And `run_worker` does not have a loop, so `to_stop.is_set()` is only checked once.

Comment: Hello is never printed. And as for the loop condition, I did not know that it required a loop.

Comment: Are you setting the global not in the worker but in the parent process? Processes don't share memory, the global variable does not change cross them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @antont, no I did not do that. How can I set it such that all subprocesses share the same memory.

Comment: One way is to use input/output pipe between the processes to send messages, not share mem. Shared men is also possible but you don't need it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate